# Is it okay to use Elmah instead of try/catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have been using [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for an MVC application and my question is

Is it a bad practice to not write try catch statement when using Elmah?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ELMAH is used to log unhandled exceptions. If you can handle the exception I would strongly suggest that you do.

If you still want to log the exceptions to ELMAH, you can do so:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e)
}
```

Comment: if i don put try catch all Exceptions will be unhandled and caught and logged by elmah ? Is it wrong ?

Comment: why should i add try catch ?can u give sm idea ?

Comment: You should add try..catch when you want to handle the exception gracefully, for example to give the user a friendly error message

Comment: suppose if i have one common error page with custom Errors ON. Do i still need that ?

Comment: No in that case a try..catch is not needed